# C# runtime application Diagnostics

Tags: c#, runtime, diagnostics

I am developing a c# GUI and was wondering if there were any (preferably free) runtime diagnostic programs available.

What Im looking for is a way to monitor user interactions with my GUI and what functions are called when. Preferably I do not want to add stacks of debug code as this has the potential to change the behaviour of the bug I am looking for.

Currently Im using Spy++ but am finding it a little heavy going as Im kinda new to this and its generating stacks of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EQATEC profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) is pretty simple to use. Free too. Started life targetting Compact Framework but since 2.00 is now geared more towards Desktop too.

Comment: From first impressions, this seems to be a nice compact profiler. 

They also produce a free Tracer program (http://www.eqatec.com/tools/) that has already proved invaluable! 

Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm).

There is a trial available, first two weeks free.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ANTS profiler have a look at JetBrain's [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler)